# Failed to Convert UTC TIME string date to Epoch time in C#

Tags: c#, azure, datetime

I read a azure health check from azure using rest api. Following is my response

```
    {
           "name": "current",          
            "reasonType": "",
            "occuredTime": "2020-07-31T11:02:22Z",
            "reasonChronicity": "Persistent",
            "reportedTime": "2020-08-22T09:36:18.1858299Z"
        
    }
```

I want to convert tthe reported time to epoch time format.
my code is

```
var azobject = saas.ToObject<JObject>();
var ty =  azobject["reportedTime"];
var ssa = DateTime.Parse(ty.ToString());

var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(ssa);
var unixDateTime = dateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Value is totally different and it always shows the local time.After processing this code,the value of  azobject["reportedTime"] format is totally different than what i get from response({22/08/2020 11:31:43 AM} theres is T and z is not present).

Comment: What are you referring to here - "it always shows the local time"? What is the "response" in "After processing this code,the value of azobject["reportedTime"] format is totally different than what i get from response"?

Comment: Please follow the answer I post to get the original data.

Comment: `I want to convert tthe reported time to epoch time format` why? Besides, the JSON string contains a value *with* an offset, so you need `DateTimeOffset.Parse`, not `DateTime.Parse`. The code you use [creates an `unspecified` DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1#kind), not UTC

Comment: What is `ty`? Why are you using `ty.ToString()`? If `ty` is a string returned as an object, you only need `(string)ty`. If it's a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` you can just use the concrete type (after a cast)

Comment: BTW if `saas` is a `JToken`-derived method you don't need `ToObject<JObject>` either. How did you call the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically because the .net json package rewrites the method of type conversion. If you want to get the same result as the original, please do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/xxxxxx?api-version=xxxx-xx-xx-xx";
            string tokenbear = "eyJ0exxxxxxPw";
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenbear);
                var test = client.GetAsync(url);
                var b = test.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(b);
                string test3 = json["properties"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(test3 + "\n");
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffffffZ",
                    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
                };
                var test2 = json["properties"]["reportedTime"];
                var _test2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test2, settings);
                _test2 = _test2.Replace("\"", "");
                Console.WriteLine(_test2.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will get the same value as the value in your response:

[image]

After obtaining the original data, you can perform the processing you want. On my side it is no problem, please have a try on your side.

Comment: The OP isn't using JSON in the question. The problem is caused by `DateTime.Parse` which returns an `Unspecified` date.